# Dialog does not get the focus after it opens (angularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I am calling the following from a button:

**var d = $dialog.dialog({dialogFade: false, modal:true, backdropClick: false});
 d.open('html/xyz.html', 'xyzController');**

All work fine except the dialog does not get the focus. it treats it as an element at the end of the page if we TAB.
is there a way to give the dialog the focus??? I tried all solution I can find but no success.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a directive to setFocus on any element:

```
MyApp.directive('CustomSetFocus', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.customSetFocus, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue === true) {                        
                        element[0].focus();                        
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then you can trigger it like so:

```
<input type="text" id="whatever" custom-set-focus="true"/>
```

Or, you can set a scope variable in your controller that will trigger the focus, maybe in an intialize() function or something like that:

```
<input type="text" id="whatever" custom-set-focus="someScopeVariable"/>
```